# Could not replace hypen from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to replace hypen from string using Javascript but as per my code its not working.

```js
function replace(){
     var str='20-03-2019';
     str.replace(/-/g,'/');
     console.log(str);
}
          
replace();
```

Here I need to replace hypen(`-`) with `/` and output should like `20/03/2019`.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable, so you need to do :

```js
function replace(){
     var str='20-03-2019';
     str = str.replace(/-/g,'/');
     alert('date ' + str);
}
          
replace();
```

Comment: Where you did the changes.

Comment: `str = str.replace` I added an assignement to the `str` variabe

Comment: yes, that it. thank you.